# Improve SAFEARRAY custom marshaler performance

Tags: c#, com

I wrote a custom marshaler for SAFEARRAY, but its performance was about twice lower than that default marshaller's performance. I perform arrays' marshaling  element by element because they may have more than 1-2 dimensions. There is a piece of code that I use for this. Can I improve my marshaler's performance?

```
void ArrayIterator::GetValue(Array^ pManagedArray, Object^% managedObject)
{
    managedObject = pManagedArray->GetValue(m_pManagedArrayIndices);
}

void ArrayIterator::GetValue(SAFEARRAY* pNativeArray, LPVOID* ppNativeValue)
{
    CHECK_HR(::SafeArrayLock(pNativeArray));
    CHECK_HR(::SafeArrayPtrOfIndex(pNativeArray, m_pNativeArrayIndices, ppNativeValue));
    CHECK_HR(::SafeArrayUnlock(pNativeArray));
}

void ArrayIterator::SetValue(Array^ pManagedArray, Object^ managedValue)
{
    pManagedArray->SetValue(managedValue, m_pManagedArrayIndices);
}

void ArrayIterator::SetValue(SAFEARRAY* pNativeArray, LPVOID pNativeValue)
{
    CHECK_HR(::SafeArrayPutElement(pNativeArray, m_pNativeArrayIndices, pNativeValue));
}

void SafeArrayMarshaler::PutManagedElementToNativeArray(SAFEARRAY* pNativeArray, ArrayIterator^ pArrayIterator, ArrayElementType^ pArrayElementType, Object^ pManagedObject)
{
    if (IsBlittableType(pArrayElementType->ManagedType))
    {
        GCHandle^ gcHandle = GCHandle::Alloc(pManagedObject, GCHandleType::Pinned);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pNativeArray, gcHandle->AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer());

        gcHandle->Free();
    }        
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_BOOL)
    {
        Boolean managedBooleanValue = safe_cast<Boolean>(pManagedObject);
        IntPtr nativeBoolPointer = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(sizeof(VARIANT_BOOL));
        VARIANT_BOOL* pNativeBool = reinterpret_cast<VARIANT_BOOL*>(nativeBoolPointer.ToPointer());

        *pNativeBool = managedBooleanValue == true ? VARIANT_TRUE : VARIANT_FALSE;

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pNativeArray, pNativeBool);

        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(nativeBoolPointer);
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_DATE)
    {
        DateTime managedDateValue = safe_cast<DateTime>(pManagedObject);
        IntPtr nativeDatePointer = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(sizeof(DATE));
        DATE* pNativeDate = reinterpret_cast<DATE*>(nativeDatePointer.ToPointer());

        *pNativeDate = managedDateValue.ToOADate();

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pNativeArray, pNativeDate);

        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(nativeDatePointer);
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_BSTR)
    {
        IntPtr nativeBSTRHandle = Marshal::StringToBSTR(safe_cast<String^>(pManagedObject));

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pNativeArray, nativeBSTRHandle.ToPointer());

        Marshal::FreeBSTR(nativeBSTRHandle);
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_INT)
    {
        IntPtr managedPointer = safe_cast<IntPtr>(pManagedObject);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pNativeArray, managedPointer.ToPointer());
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_UINT)
    {
        UIntPtr managedPointer = safe_cast<UIntPtr>(pManagedObject);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pNativeArray, managedPointer.ToPointer());
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_DISPATCH)
    {
        IntPtr nativeInterfacePointer = Marshal::GetIDispatchForObject(pManagedObject);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pNativeArray, nativeInterfacePointer.ToPointer());

        Marshal::Release(nativeInterfacePointer);
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_UNKNOWN)
    {
        IntPtr nativeInterfacePointer = Marshal::GetIUnknownForObject(pManagedObject);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pNativeArray, nativeInterfacePointer.ToPointer());

        Marshal::Release(nativeInterfacePointer);
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_VARIANT)
    {
        IntPtr nativeVariantHandle = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(sizeof(VARIANT));

        Marshal::GetNativeVariantForObject(pManagedObject, nativeVariantHandle);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pNativeArray, nativeVariantHandle.ToPointer());

        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(nativeVariantHandle);
    }
    else
    {
        throw gcnew InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

void SafeArrayMarshaler::PutNativeElementToManagedArray(Array^ pManagedArray, ArrayIterator^ pArrayIterator, ArrayElementType^ pArrayElementType, LPVOID pNativeObject)
{
    if (IsBlittableType(pArrayElementType->ManagedType))
    {
        switch (Type::GetTypeCode(pArrayElementType->ManagedType))
        {
            case TypeCode::SByte:
            {
                SByte managedSignedByte = Marshal::ReadByte(IntPtr(pNativeObject));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedSignedByte);
                break;
            }

            case TypeCode::Byte:
            {
                Byte managedUnsignedByte = Marshal::ReadByte(IntPtr(pNativeObject));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedUnsignedByte);
                break;
            }

            case TypeCode::Int16:
            {
                Int16 managedValue = Marshal::ReadInt16(IntPtr(pNativeObject));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedValue);
                break;
            }

            case TypeCode::UInt16:
            {
                UInt16 managedValue = Marshal::ReadInt16(IntPtr(pNativeObject));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedValue);
                break;
            }

            case TypeCode::Int32:
            {
                Int32 managedValue = Marshal::ReadInt32(IntPtr(pNativeObject));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedValue);
                break;
            }

            case TypeCode::UInt32:
            {
                UInt32 managedValue = Marshal::ReadInt32(IntPtr(pNativeObject));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedValue);
                break;
            }

            case TypeCode::Int64:
            {
                Int64 managedValue = Marshal::ReadInt64(IntPtr(pNativeObject));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedValue);
                break;
            }

            case TypeCode::UInt64:
            {
                UInt64 managedValue = Marshal::ReadInt64(IntPtr(pNativeObject));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedValue);
                break;
            }

            case TypeCode::Single:
            {
                Single managedValue;
                pin_ptr<Single> pManagedValue = &managedValue;

                ::memcpy_s(pManagedValue, Marshal::SizeOf(Single::typeid), pNativeObject, Marshal::SizeOf(Single::typeid));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedValue);
                break;
            }

            case TypeCode::Double:
            {
                Double managedValue;
                pin_ptr<Double> pManagedValue = &managedValue;

                ::memcpy_s(pManagedValue, Marshal::SizeOf(Double::typeid), pNativeObject, Marshal::SizeOf(Double::typeid));
                pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, managedValue);
                break;
            }

            default:
                throw gcnew NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_BOOL)
    {
        VARIANT_BOOL* pNativeBooleanValue = reinterpret_cast<VARIANT_BOOL*>(pNativeObject);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, *pNativeBooleanValue == VARIANT_TRUE ? true : false);
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_DATE)
    {
        DATE* pNativeDateValue = reinterpret_cast<DATE*>(pNativeObject);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, DateTime::FromOADate(*pNativeDateValue));
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_BSTR)
    {
        String^ pManagedString = Marshal::PtrToStringBSTR(IntPtr(*reinterpret_cast<void**>(pNativeObject)));

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, pManagedString);
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_INT)
    {
        INT_PTR nativePointer = reinterpret_cast<INT_PTR>(pNativeObject);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, IntPtr(nativePointer));
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_UINT)
    {
        UINT_PTR nativePointer = reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(pNativeObject);

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, UIntPtr(nativePointer));
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_DISPATCH ||
             pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_UNKNOWN)
    {
        Object^ pManagedObject = Marshal::GetObjectForIUnknown(IntPtr(*reinterpret_cast<void**>(pNativeObject)));

        pArrayIterator->GetValue(pManagedArray, pManagedObject);
    }
    else if (pArrayElementType->NativeType == VT_VARIANT)
    {
        Object^ pManagedObject = Marshal::GetObjectForNativeVariant(IntPtr(pNativeObject));

        pArrayIterator->SetValue(pManagedArray, pManagedObject);
    }
    else
    {
        throw gcnew InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can I improve my marshaler's performance" - perhaps you should first set out why you're writing your own and not using the default one - what are the essential differences? What if the improvements happen to introduce the very features that are present in the default one and that you're trying to avoid? Or vice versa?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, because default marshaler perform multidimensional SAFEARRAYs' marshaling incorrectly - with inverted dimensions.